# Reading an excel file, extracting each cell value as a string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, list

I have following excel file:

[image: my excel file]

I need to save each value in a list as strings.

I am new to python, I have already read the file in a  dataframe. Please help further.

```py
df = pd.read_excel(userfile, converters={'Agentcode':str})
```

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: Your code looks correct. What issue are you getting?